# Animation alpha не добавляет значения alpha канала если картинка прозрачная

Tags: android, android-sdk

Изначально ImageView полностью прозрачный 0.0, я прикрепляю к нему эффект анимации прозрачности, но не увеличивается значение альфа-канала прозрачности.

А если изначально ImageView сделать не прозрачным, то есть когда альфа канал равен 255 или (float)1.0, то все хорошо отрабатывает.

Как сделать что бы изначально ImageView был прозрачным, а потом постепенно становился непрозрачным.

```
<alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.2"
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:toAlpha="0.6" >
</alpha>


<scale
    android:startOffset="0"
    android:duration="600"
    android:fromXScale="1.0"
    android:fromYScale="1.0"
    android:pivotX="50%"
    android:pivotY="50%"
    android:toXScale="30.0"
    android:toYScale="30.0" />


<alpha
    android:duration="300"
    android:fromAlpha="0.6"
    android:startOffset="300"
    android:toAlpha="0.0" >
</alpha>
```

Answer (score 1):

До воспроизведения анимации задайте вашему `imageView` `setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`. После прокрутки анимации вызовите `View.VISIBLE`

**UPD**

Можно еще попробовать так:

```
 <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:fillAfter="true"
        android:fillEnabled="true"
        android:alpha=".0"/>
```

Получится полностью прозрачный объект. А вот эти параметры

```
android:fillAfter="true"
android:fillEnabled="true"
```

по идее должны гарантировать сохранение состояния View после анимации. Надо проверять

Comment: Андройд Андройд Я думал так сделать. А по другому не как? Это получается что в супер-замедленном состоянии формируется вот такое алгоритм: появляется 1.объект на весь экран 2.делаем его полностью прозрачным. 3. увеличиваем его непрозрачность, повышая значения альфа-канала.  А хотелось бы вот такое алгоритм: 1.Появляется полностью прозрачный объект 2. увеличиваем его непрозрачность, повышая значения альфа-канала.

Comment: обновил ответ, проверьете

Comment: Андройд Андройд не хочет работать. Объект просто прозрачный, и все.

Comment: Хм, странно. Но уверен, что надо копать в этом направлении

Comment: @semiromid Вы можете перед тем как добавить картинку в ImageView сделать её невидимой методом ImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE), тогда даже в супер-пупер замедленном состоянии не будет видно, что что-то там успело появиться.

Answer (score 0):

Вот XML файл анимации появления, 100% работает

```
<set xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shareInterpolator="false" >

    <alpha
        android:duration="1000"
        android:fromAlpha="0.0"
        android:toAlpha="1.0" >
    </alpha>

</set>
```

Comment: 100%?) А если вы сделаете анимируемый объект изначально прозрачным? То работать просто так не будет. Придется регулировать alpha анимацию самого объекта, то есть перед начало анимации устанавливать setAlpha=1.0. Но так мне делать не рнавитсья, потому я изначально задал свой вопрос.

Comment: @semiromid Каким образом? Вы про SetVisibility?

Comment: BORSHEVIK  в моём случаи SetVisibility не подходит. Я отредактировал свой комментарий выше, посмотрите пожалуйста его.

Comment: @semiromid Я вас, кажется понял. Вы о том, что у вас картинка изначально прозрачная, т.е. у неё задан параметр Alpha. Если вы об этом, то вам нужно попробовать не Animation, а ObjectAnimation, их различие в том, что Animation служит лишь для визуальных эффектов, а ОbjectAnimation изменяет также и свойства объекта. Но данный способ не поможет, если вы задали прозрачность в цвете, т.е. 2 первых символа в параметре Color, только если изменяли специальный пункт Alpha

Comment: BORSHEVIK Ух-Ты! Интересно! Сейчас же попробую!